# Oracle SQL Order By Random

Tags: sql, oracle, sorting

In my database, I have multiple records for each ID. And in my output, I want to sort the rows by DATE for each ID, while IDs are shown randomly eventually.

This is my code which worked but shows sorted IDs, without random IDs:

```
SELECT ID,  VALUE, DATE
FROM TABLE
ORDER BY ID, DATE DESC;
```

I tried to change it to

```
SELECT ID,  VALUE, DATE
FROM TABLE
ORDER BY ID, dbms_random.value, DATE DESC;
```

but it didn't work and gave me this error:

```
ORA-01652: unable to extend temp segment by 64 in tablespace TEMP01
```

My guess is that I have no more disk to allocate to my TEMP tablespace, but how to modify it?
Besides, I am not sure if I used dbms_random.value correctly, did I?

---

To further illustrate my idea about showing random IDs eventually, please see the following example:

Origial:

```
ID    VALUE    DATE
1     200     1/2/2013
1     300     3/26/2013
2     200     2/2/2013
3     100     2/3/2015
3     500     6/21/2014
3     200     5/3/2014
```

Desired:

```
ID    VALUE    DATE
2     200     2/2/2013
3     200     5/3/2014
3     500     6/21/2014
3     100     2/3/2015
1     200     1/2/2013
1     300     3/26/2013
```

Comment: How big is the real-world `TABLE`?

Comment: I'm extracting tree columns from my original data, which has 82,000,000 rows and 50 columns

Comment: What is the business purpose of the random sort?  It's possible.  But it's going to be insanely expensive to do on an 82 million row table.  Are you really, really sure that the business purpose justifies that sort of expense?

Comment: You have a good point. The random sorted data is just to make sure I will have random samples for my further analysis. If I don't do the random sorting, then I have to choose random samples later. However, I don't really know how to do random sampling in SQL.

Comment: You might consider using the `ROWNUM` pseudocolumn with a random value to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want a random sample, use the `sample` clause or some other technique.  If approximate numbers are sufficient, then you can get a 1% sample by doing:

```
SELECT ID,  VALUE, DATE
FROM TABLE SAMPLE (1);
```

Another method would be:

```
WITH t AS (
      SELECT t.*, dbms_random.value as rnd
      FROM TABLE t
     )
SELECT ID, VALUE, DATE
FROM t
WHERE rnd < 0.01
```

I'm not sure what type of sampling you want (strict random, stratified, cluster sampling, and so on).  However, sorting all 80,000,000 rows should not be necessary.

Comment: You are right, sorting all 80,000,000 rows is really not necessary. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: `... WHERE dbms_random.value < 0.01` will randomly return all or nothing.  You'll have to randomly incorporate dbms_random.value into the dataset somehow, such as: `with t as (select id, value, date, dbms_random.value rand from table) select id, value, date from t where rand < 0.01;`